# Long delay when submiting form onload?

Tags: asp.net, html

To post data to a remote payment server, my website generates a page that looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body onload="document.form1.submit()">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="https://secure.paymentsite.com/purchase" >
      <input type="hidden" name="instId" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="23">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I generate a page like this so that I can log the choice the user has made to my database before redirecting the user to an external site to pay.

However, it takes around 6 seconds for the form to be submited once the page loads. During this time, the user is displayed a plain white screen, and may wonder if the website is broken.

Is it possible to make a form that submits as soon as the page has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery's $(document).ready(function(){....} executes when the DOM has finished loading.  That would be one of many solutions.

Comment: So how come I have this problem? Are browsers specifically implemented to work in this way - to have a long delay before the onload event is fired?

Comment: The load event fires after the browser has received all of its data.  The time the DOM is ready and the time the browser ready doesn't usually coincide; the DOM will always be ready first.